# pyspark-strange behavior of alias function when used in agg() after pivot

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am facing a strange behavior while using alias function to rename columns within agg() after pivoting.
This code works:

```
tst = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1,2,3,4),(3,2,5,4),(5,3,7,5),(7,3,9,5)],schema=['col1','col2','col3','col4'])
chk= tst.groupby('col1').pivot('col2').agg(F.sum('col3').alias('sum'),F.mean('col3').alias('mean'))
```

When I check the columns for this df, the name are as expected

```
chk.columns
Out[54]: ['col1', '2_sum', '2_mean', '3_sum', '3_mean']
```

But when I have just one aggregation, followed by pivot, the renaming does not work.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
#Test data
tst = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1,2,3,4),(3,2,5,4),(5,3,7,5),(7,3,9,5)],schema=['col1','col2','col3','col4'])
chk= tst.groupby('col1').pivot('col2').agg(F.sum('col3').alias('sum'))
```

Now, when I check the column results, the renaming does not work

```
chk.columns
Out[56]: ['col1', '2', '3']
```

Is this an expected behavior in spark? Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wanted to look at the spark git source code for [pivot](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/plans/logical/basicLogicalOperators.scala#L757)

```scala
 override def output: Seq[Attribute] = {
    val pivotAgg = aggregates match {
      case agg :: Nil =>
        pivotValues.map(value => AttributeReference(value.toString, agg.dataType)())
      case _ =>
        pivotValues.flatMap { value =>
          aggregates.map(agg => AttributeReference(value + "_" + agg.sql, agg.dataType)())
        }
    }
    groupByExprsOpt.getOrElse(Seq.empty).map(_.toAttribute) ++ pivotAgg
  }
```

**you can observe output cols is not getting appended by the `agg.sql` when there is only one aggrgate expression after pivot**

when there is single aggregate expression, output attribute is provided the `pivot value` as name -

```
pivotValues.map(value => AttributeReference(value.toString, agg.dataType)())
```

**Conclusion-**
This behaviour is expected and not strange.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. Any purpose it is kept this way?

Comment: not sure about the intent, but i guess there is no need attaching the aggregate alias for 1 aggregation and hence they are not attaching the same. but I agree the behaviour should have been same for 1 and more than 1 aggregation